# Can I emulate a Bluetooth keyboard with my Android device?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, emulators

I'd like to use an Android phone for controlling presentations. I know there are some WiFi approaches, but often times the computer running the slideshow isn't owned by me and is not comfortable installing and running other software, especially stuff designed for remote control.

So I'm specifically looking for some way to do this using the Bluetooth HID profile, as it requires very little set-up on the PC side. Basically, I'm looking for the Android equivalent to [BlueMaemo](https://web.archive.org/web/20140805094307/http://www.valeriovalerio.org/?page_id=174).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Just saw this: [AndroidSpin: Turn your Android Into a Keyboard and Mouse for Your Playstation 3 or PC](https://web.archive.org/web/20160819231956/http://androidspin.com/2011/02/28/turn-your-android-into-a-keyboard-and-mouse-for-your-playstation-3-or-pc)

> Another reason we all love technology, thanks to some clever development by XDA member berserker_devel, you can now use your rooted Android device as a keyboard or mouse on your Playstation 3. The app, BlueputDroid, has been released in beta form and allows your phone’s screen to be used as a cursor and virtual or physical keyboard to input text. This app could also be used for your PC, for those that really want the most from there device(s). Either way it could save you quite a bit of money on buying wireless input devices for your toys (provided they have bluetooth and are supported).

A limited number of devices are supported at present, but it's being actively developed, so something to keep an eye on even if it doesn't cover your device right now.

Comment: Promising, but the reviews are not looking good. https://market.android.com/details?id=berserker.android.apps.blueputdroid

Comment: A good comment on there today ;) Current lack of Windows support will be a problem for most, but this is the one to watch.

Answer (score 3):

There's an app project on Google code that does this: [AndroHID](https://code.google.com/p/androhid/).

It doesn't offer you a full keyboard, it's meant more as a remote for wireless presenting or audio/video controls, etc. (much like older SonyEricsson feature phones, e.g. the K- or W-series did). You need root.

It seems inactive at the moment (last release from 2010) and it is not in the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

You could download [TeamViewer for Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20110129051820/http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mobile.aspx) and then download [TeamViewer Portable](https://web.archive.org/web/20110129002009/http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx) (scroll down some).  This way, you could run TeamViewer from your USB drive without having to install it and then connect with TeamViewer for Android.  I have used it to connect to my home computer and download some files - it works great on my EVO.

I couldn't wait to try it so I gave it a shot.  It works pretty well but you can only access the main display (can't point things out with the mouse on a secondary display).  Also, I needed to enable the "Presenter View" so that I could click the "Next" arrow since the presentation was on the secondary display. The computer I tried it on was on WiFi and my EVO was on 3G.

Comment: Works very well, and has impressive support for Linux (Fedora 19 + Android 4) - it was used to type  this comment :-) - including this link to [the best Android on-screen jeybaord](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en), which was also used for this. i now just need to work out how to scroll...

Answer (score 0):

Native support for BT HID is [going to appear in Android P](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-p-bluetooth-keyboard-mouse/).

> Android P adds support for the Bluetooth HID device profile, which allows Android smartphones to be used as a Bluetooth keyboard or mouse for connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bluetooth Keyboard & Mouse app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek) emulates a real Bluetooth keyboard that you can connect with every device that accepts Bluetooth keyboard.

This is possible because, since Android 9, Bluetooth HID became available to apps.